# Reverse function on another function result?

Tags: haskell

Is it possible to use the reverse function on a user-defined function?

So the usermade function gives you a result and I then want to reverse that result.

```
mult_add d s = d + 10*s

form_number_back d = foldr mult_add 0 d
```

Function to reverse the above result

```
form_number_front d = reverse [d form_number_back]
```

I am reversing a list with form_number_back... then reversing it back with form_number_front.

I have also tried foldl with no results.

Comment: You can apply `reverse` to any list, no matter where it comes from.

Comment: well do you know why form_number_front d = reverse[form_number_back] does not work.. it keeps coming up with an error like 
<interactive>:1:1:
    No instance for (Show ([b0] -> b0))
      arising from a use of `print'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Show ([b0] -> b0))
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it

Comment: Well, yes, that's because you're trying to reverse a list with one element, the function `form_number_back`.  Try applying `form_number_back` to an *argument.*

Comment: The problem here is what you're applying reverse to. What do you expect the output of `[d form_number_back]` to be?

Comment: I'm sorry I dont understand how to do that in Haskell. Do you mean assign it to a variable? something like form_number_front d = reverse [x] where x = form_number_back(d) ? Thats probably gibberish...

Comment: @ kkovali.. i'm not sure how to pass the list(d) into form_number_back so it can do its thing...

Comment: Well I'm assuming `d` is the argument you're passing into `form_number_back`? If so, it should be after the function name not before. Also the output of `form_number_back` is actually a value not a list.

Comment: I can pass the number through now.. but reverse doesn't work 
form_number_front x = reverse[form_number_back(x)]

Comment: Well that's because you're reversing a singleton list. All you're doing there is applying `form_number_back` to `x` which returns a value, which you're making into a singleton list and reversing. Reversing a list with one element will just return that same element.

Comment: Ok so I have to figure out how to reverse a string?..

Comment: You could write a function to convert the int into a string, reverse it and convert it back. Just a tip, a String is actually just a list of characters. So a string is already a list. Look up `show` and `read `for conversion.

Comment: You make it sound like thats not a big deal :p Thanks I will look into that...

Comment: Would you have a link to a good tutorial on show/read? Can't find crap on it. 4 days of searching for documentation on haskell... so tired of this language :/

Answer (score 1):

```
form_number_front d = reverse [d form_number_back]
```

There are a number of things wrong with this.

First, `form_number_back` is a function, and `d` is a number you wish to pass to that function. The function must appear to the left of its argument:

```
form_number_front d = reverse [form_number_back d]
```

More substantively, `reverse` is for reversing *lists*. But the result of calling `form_number_back` is a *number*; you appear to want to reverse the digits in that number.

Now, you could try reversing the list *before* `form_number_back` turns it into a number:

```
form_number_front d = form_number_back (reverse d)
```

You could try rewriting `form_number_back` to fold the list in the order you want:

```
form_number_front d = foldl (flip mult_add) 0 d
```

Does this help?